# Rails - order by, with grouped_collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, select

This **input select box** shows a list of `issues` based on the selection of another **input select box** that displays the values in my `School.rb` model. But, this lists the `issues` by the issue_id. I need it to list and sort the `name` column of my `Issue.rb` model in alphabetical order.

I've tried every combination I can think of!

Thanks in advance..

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :issue_id, School.all, :issues, :name, :id, :name, :prompt => ""%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shot in the dark without seeing your models:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :issue_id, School.all, :issues, :name, :id, :name, :include_blank => true %>
```

Then add a default scope to your issues model.

```
default_scope :order => 'issues.name ASC'
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this error: `undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol`

Comment: On my phone right now so I can't test it but try your original method that sorts improperly but add the default scope to your model.

Comment: I want to hug you. this stumped me for a couple hours.

Answer (score 1):

I would be hesitant to enter a default scope in general, although probably benign in this case.  Instead you can just add a method on the school model and call it from the select.

in _form:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :issue_id, School.all, :ordered_issues, :name, :id, :name, :prompt => ""%>
```

in school.rb:

```
def ordered_issues
  issues.order(:name)
end
```

You can also order the schools alphabetically by passing `School.order(:name)` in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Just try,

```
<%= f.select("issue_id", School.find(:all, :order => "name").collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'None'}) %>
```

Comment: This is close, and listed them in alpha order.. but now my choices aren't narrowed down based on the selection of the first select input box.. it just lists everything in my column.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5 deprecated the syntax of @Larry McKenzie answer. This now becomes:

```
default_scope { order('issues.name ASC') }
```